# Behaviour of "Defines Module = Yes" for testing a project

Tags: ios, xcode

My Swift/Obj-C hybrid project is setup with two targets:

`MyProject` and `MyProjectTests`

In order to write unit tests (using `XCTest`), I have the following configurations for the main target (`MyProject`) build settings:

```
Enable testability = Yes
Defines module = Yes
```

This works fine, but I would like to know what is actually going on when I specify `Defines module = Yes`.

Does specifying `Defines module = Yes` mean:

- A framework is created for the target, or at least a module map, or an umbrella header for the target?

  - If it's this case, i.e. there are at least temporary build files generated to make the main target look like a module, then where are they usually located? In `DerivedData`?
- Or does Xcode have some special treatment for the main project target, such that turning on the `Defines Module = Yes` flag does nothing filesystem-wise, but still allows the main project target to be imported as a (testable) module in a test target?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? If so I would be very interested in the answer.

Comment: No updates yet, though when you write out `@testable import ProjectName`, you can command-option-click the `ProjectName` portion in Xcode, which would bring you to a seemingly empty file representing your framework module. Will update here if I get any more new findings!

Answer (score 4):

Making app work with both Swift and Objective-C, can be a delicate process. You must adopt modules if you want a hybrid project. When bringing old Objective-C code to a Swift project, this means setting the “Defines Module” (`DEFINES_MODULE`) build setting to `YES` in the framework target. This instructs Xcode to install a `module.modulemap` file (and possibly a `module.private.modulemap`) alongside the headers in the framework. Objective-C frameworks need to define a module to be used by Swift.

Source: [Big Nerd Ranch](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/it-looks-like-youre-still-trying-to-use-a-framework/)